# Gerar id dinâmico no html e pegar com JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tenho uma tabela no HTML que recebe os valores vindo do banco de dados. 
Cada linha da tabela, ao ser clicado no icone preciso pegar os valores desta linha e ao abrir o modal mostrar essas informações no modal.

Minha tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando for clicado nesse icone de editar eu preciso pegar o valor da linha referente [vlor Programado] | [Dt Vencto] | [Documento], para exibir no modal.

O problema é, como os valores dessas linhas são dinâmicos eu não consigo atribuir um `id` para `<td>` para poder pega-lo com JS.

```html
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Vlr Programado</th>
            <th>Dt Vencto</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>2019-01-18</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a id="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="3"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>2019-02-17</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a id="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="4"><i class="fas fa-edit"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" align="center">
                <div class="pagination-wrap">
                    <ul class="pagination"><li><a href="/sistema/instancias/receita/add-data.php?page_no=1" style="color:red;">1</a></li></ul>                                                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Têm alguma forma de fazer esse procedimento?

Comment: Existem várias formas, mas eu não entendi exatamente qual o problema

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara mas acho que entendi. Você precisa adicionar o evento em um elemento fixo a observar o click a partir dele: `$(document).on('click','#btnPrepend',function(){//do something})` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript

Comment: Poste o JS que você tentou fazer também...

Comment: Pq está repetindo os id's `id="omdleditreceita"`? Um id é igual CPF, deve ser único.

Comment: "_...em cada linha preciso pegar para exibir em um modal..._"... "_pegar_" oq? O primeiro parágrafo da sua pergunta tá muito confuso.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta, sobre o `id` está se repetindo foi só para exemplificar o que o navegador esté renderizando. @Sam.

Comment: @edsonalves vi aqui esse tópico mais não entendi muito bem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um evento `click` e pegue os valores de cada coluna usando `td:eq()`, onde `td:eq(0)` é a primeiro coluna, `td:eq(1)` a segunda e assim por diante

O evento você pega pelo atributo `[data-idparcela]` que todos os `<a>` dos ícones possuem em comum:

```js
$("[data-idparcela]").on("click", function(){
   
   // pega a linha do ícone clicado
   var t = $(this).closest("tr");
   
   var documento = t.find("td:eq(0)").text();
   var valor = t.find("td:eq(1)").text();
   var vencimento = t.find("td:eq(2)").text();
   
   console.log(documento, valor, vencimento);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Documento</th>
            <th>Vlr Programado</th>
            <th>Dt Vencto</th>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody><tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>2019-01-18</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a id="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="3"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FR212</td>
            <td>500</td>
            <td>2019-02-17</td>
            <td align="center">
                <a id="omdleditreceita" data-idparcela="4"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" align="center">
                <div class="pagination-wrap">
                    <ul class="pagination"><li><a href="/sistema/instancias/receita/add-data.php?page_no=1" style="color:red;">1</a></li></ul>                                                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Com as variáveis alimentadas, você pode jogar para dentro da modal. Como você não mostrou a modal a nem informou como quer que essas informações apareçam nela, aí não tem como dizer mais além disso.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado, não iria conseguir resolver senão fosse esse exemplo, ainda não tinha visto essa forma, valeu mesmo.
No modal eu só quero exibir esses dados, só pega o input HTML e atribui o valor retornado nesse caso o valor de vencimento e os demais.

Comment: De nada colega! Boa sorte aí nos seus projetos!

Comment: sabe seé possivél pegar o valor individual de cada td sem ser clicando na linha?

Comment: Eu preciso somar as duas linhas para verificar se bate com o valor original, pesquisei bastante e tentei aqui diversas formas mais não conseguir uma solução.

Comment: Mas vc quer somar na hora do click ou quando carrega a página?

Comment: Valeu @Sam, consegui a solução da soma.